# DefaultListModel in Java modifies a String passed as an argument to addElement method

Tags: java, string-formatting, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am facing an interesting issue trying to output POJO loaded from a database into JList using DefaultListModel.
Briefly, this is my code:

```
        // load POJO objects from the DB
        PersonData[] allUsers = loadAllUserData();

        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

        // fill in (with) the data
        for (int i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
            listModel.addElement(formPersonDataStringRepresentation(allUsers[i]));
        }

        JList list = new JList(listModel);
        usersList = new JScrollPane(list);
```

Method that takes PersonData object and generates a String looks as presented:

```
private String formPersonDataStringRepresentation(PersonData personData) {

        // ... checking the argument ...

        // ... formatting ...
        return String.format("%-17s%-17s", personData.getUsername(),
                personData.getForename()
                );
    }
```

What happens is that my output looks different when printed to Console vs. when used as an argument in DefaultListModel although same formatting *"%-17s%-17s"* is used.

I am attaching a screenshot of the Console and Swing output for better understanding.

[image: Comparison of the output printed from console and the one generated by JList using the same String data]

Do I have to avoid using DefaultListModel in such a case?

Comment: It looks formatted the same to me -- but you realize the console is a monospace font, and the default (Arial?) in Swing is not, right?

Comment: You are correct, setting the the Font for JList explicitly 
list.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
changed the way output looked. I should have checked generated whitespaces, my bad.

Comment: Excellent -- I reposted this as an answer for future Googlers.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was waiting for. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the spaces, it's the font -- the console is monospaced, and Swing uses something else (Arial?) by default.

As discovered in the question comments, you can simply change the default Swing font to a monospaced font with:

```
list.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

to have it match the console formatting more closely.